# apache redirect on minimal querystring

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to redirect all urls as such:

```
http://somewebsite.com/?49084034
http://somewebsite.com/?434554
http://somewebsite.com/?656565
...
http://somewebsite.com/?xxxxxx [any random number]
```

to:

http://somewesite.com

what would go into htaccess please to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: wried, do you any existing rule/code that is adding `/?123456` in the URIs?